# designer.cs when using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I made a MVC asp.net project، Then I choose a new item and select ADO.NET entity Data Model and add it to the project. when ask me "What should the model contain" I select "EF Designer from database" then I made a new connection and I choose Entity Framework 6 then select my tables and finish. now I can see my tables in diagram models (EmployeeModel.edmx).

my problem is that when I select Employeemodel.Designer.cs it does not show me clasess and ...

i am using visual studio 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your classes are not in EmployeeModel.Designer.cs but below EmployeeModel.tt after you save the edmx file (CTRL+S) (When you save it it generates automatically the classes with TT template)

[image: model]